# for/if loop to run a function multiple times depending on input :: jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing a slider from scratch, no plugins.

I have my slider working, based on adding the slides together and plus or minus the length of the slider window. 
It has become complicated when pagination needs to be added. I can't seem to wrap my head around the logic of the function needed to be written that states.

if button 1 is clicked run the function 1 time and go to slide one.

if button 2 is clicked run the function 2 times and go to slide two. .... and so on..

The issue I see coming from this is if on slide 3 and the button 4 is clicked the function only needs to move once not 4 times!! This is where my head breaks and all logic spills out of my ears.

How do I go about writing something like this?

here is the jsfiddle I have so far. http://jsfiddle.net/r5DY8/2/

Any help would be appreciated.

:: all the code on one page if you don't want to use jsfiddle ::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js'type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marmelad' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    font-family: 'Marmelad', sans-serif;
   -moz-user-select: none; 
   -webkit-user-select: none; 
   -ms-user-select:none; 
   user-select:none;
 }

#slideContainer {
position: relative;
width: 990px;
height: 275px;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
margin-top:5%;
margin-left:15%;
  }

 #slideWrap {
width: 3960px;
height: 275px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
 }

.slide {
width: 990px;
height: 275px;
float: left;
 }

.slide:first-child  { background-color: #009999; } 
.slide:nth-child(2) { background-color: #CC0033; }
.slide:nth-child(3) { background-color: #FFFF66; }
.slide:nth-child(4) { background-color: #006699; }

 #clickLeft{
color: black;
float: left;
margin: 12% 0% 0 15%;
/*background: url("prev.png") no-repeat;*/
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
cursor: pointer;
list-style: none;
position: absolute;
z-index: 9;
border:1px solid black;/**/
 }
#clickRight{
color: black;
float: right;
margin: 12% 0 0 79.5%;
/*background: url("next.png") no-repeat;*/
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
cursor: pointer;
list-style: none;
position: absolute;
border:1px solid black;/**/
 }
 .dots{
width: 9%;
position: absolute;
top: 310px;
text-align: center;
height: 45px;
padding-top: 5px;
background: white;
left: 43.5%;
border-radius: 8px;
list-style:none;
 }
 .dots li {
display: inline-block; 
list-style:none;
 }
.dots li:first-child {
margin-left:-40px;
 }

.dots li a{
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
display: block;
background: #ededed;
cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
margin: 5px;
 }

 .dots li a:hover { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); }
 .styleDots { background: #a4acb2; }
 .active { background: #a4acb2; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -o-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;}
 li.pagerItem{

 }
</style>
 <script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

var currentSlidePosition = 0;                           
var slideW = 990;                                            
var allSlides = $('.slide');                            
var numberOfSlides = allSlides.length;                  
var marker;                                             

$('.slide').each(function(i) { 
    listNumber=i+1;
    marker = $("<li>");
    marker.addClass('pagerItem '+listNumber);
    $("<a href='#' ></a>").appendTo(marker);
        if (i===0){
        marker.addClass('active'); 
        }
        marker.appendTo($(".dots")); 
});

allSlides.wrapAll('<div id="moveSlide"></div>').css({'float' : 'left','width' : slideW}); 

$('#moveSlide').css('width', slideW * numberOfSlides); 

$('body').prepend('<li class="controls" id="clickLeft"></li>') 
         .append('<li class="controls" id="clickRight"></li>');


$('.controls').click(function(){ 
moveSlide(this);

moveSlide(this); // running twice because the function is being called twice
//create a function that says if button 1 is clicked run the function 1 time if button 3 is clicked run the function 3 times..

  });


var moveSlide = function(thisobject){
console.log('function run');
    if(($(thisobject).attr('id')=='clickRight')) { 
                if(currentSlidePosition == numberOfSlides-1)currentSlidePosition=0; 
                 else currentSlidePosition++;   

                 var active = $(".active").removeClass('active');
                    if(active.next() && active.next().length){
                        active.next().addClass('active');
                    } else {
                        active.siblings(":first").addClass('active');
                    }

                } else if($(thisobject).attr('id')=='clickLeft'){ 
                    if(currentSlidePosition == 0)currentSlidePosition=numberOfSlides-1;                     
                     else currentSlidePosition--;

                    var active = $(".active").removeClass('active');
                    if(active.prev() && active.prev().length){
                        active.prev().addClass('active');
                    } else {
                        active.siblings(":last").addClass('active');
                    }

                }

                $('#moveSlide').animate({'margin-left' : slideW*(-currentSlidePosition)}); 
    }
 });        




</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slideContainer">
        <div id="slideWrap">
            <div class="slide">1</div>
            <div class="slide">2</div>
            <div class="slide">3</div>
            <div class="slide">4</div>
    </div>

</div>
    <ul class="dots"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more complicated than just calling the function a number of times. As the animation is asynchronous, you need to call the function again when the animation has finished, not right away.

Add a callback parameter to the function so that it can use that do do something when the animation finishes:

```
var moveSlide = function (thisobject, callback) {
```

Add the callback to the animation:

```
  $('#moveSlide').animate({
    'margin-left': slideW * (-currentSlidePosition)
  }, callback);
```

Make a function `moveTo` that will call `moveSlide` in the right direction, and use itself as callback:

```
function moveTo(target){
    if (target < currentSlidePosition) {
        moveSlide($('#clickLeft'), function(){ moveTo(target); });
    } else if (target > currentSlidePosition) {
        moveSlide($('#clickRight'), function(){ moveTo(target); });
    }
}
```

Bind the click event to the links in the dots. Use the `index` method to find out which slide you want to go to, and call `moveTo` to do it:

```
$('.dots a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).parent().index();
    moveTo(target);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/r5DY8/3/

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I needed, I have never used a callback before, I understand the rest of the code but this eludes me. 
could you explain please what it means. :)

Comment: @LadyRhaebosis: A callback is just a reference to a function to call when something happens, usually when something has completed. The `animate` function is asynchronous, i.e. it uses timers to do the animation so that the browser can do other things in between. To allow you to know when an animation has completed it allows a callback.

Answer (score 0):

From a purely logical point of view (assumes the existence of two variables - `curr_slide_num` and `butt_num`):

```
for (var i=0; i < Math.abs(curr_slide_num - butt_num); i++) my_func();
```

Be careful of zero indexing; either treat the first button and first slide as number 0, or neither, else the maths will break down.

This takes no account of the *direction* the slider should move. I haven't looked at your Fiddle but I guess you would pass direction as an argument to the function. Let's say the function expects direction as its first argument - the string 'left' or 'right'

```
for (var i=0; i < Math.abs(curr_slide_num - butt_num); i++)
    my_func(curr_slide_num < butt_num ? 'left' : 'right');
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but using math was not the way I wanted to go because the question of clicking left or right was inside the function that controls the slider; not on the outside and easily referenced.
At least not with my knowledge as it stands now. :)